# How to use dismissible widget with provider state management in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am trying to add `dismissible widget` to delete item from the `list of items`. I am using to `provider` for state management. to delete the item I have done something like this in `changeNotifier` file.

> task_data.dart

```
void deleteTask(Task task) {
    _tasks.remove(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

> task_list_view.dart

Here i am passing  deleteTask to my `Task_tile.dart`

```
child: new TaskListTile(
                  taskTitle: taskData.tasks[index].name,
                  isChecked: taskData.tasks[index].isDone,

                  checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
                    taskData.updateTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
                  },
                  deleteCallback: (){
                    taskData.deleteTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
                  },
                ),
```

> list_tile_view.dart

Here I add dismissible widget to execute my deleteCallback.

```
final Function deleteCallback;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: Key(taskTitle),
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        deleteCallback;  <-- Here i get error by idle saying avoid unecessary statement.
      },
```

I have no idea why this is comming. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute your function.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Dismissible(
    key: Key(taskTitle),
    onDismissed: (direction) {
      deleteCallback();
    },
  );
}
```